# Is there a way to prevent mobile keyboard from showing up without blocking desktop input?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using a jquery date picker in my website. (I am using [this one](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker) currently, but may use other library if necessary) It allows the user to input date using the date picker popup or directly inputting the date using keyboard. The problem is this also makes the mobile keyboard popup when the site is viewed on mobile device, and sometimes make the date picker having not enough room for display in smaller device.

I know I can prevent this behavior by adding `readonly`, `disabled` or lose focus on click. However, this also stops users from inputting through keyboard on desktop. Is there a way I can just stop mobile keyboard from showing up?

Comment: You can use a media query with user-select: none; for the input field

Comment: @Gerard I have just tried, `user-select: none` does not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
var width = jQuery(window).width();
if(width > 768) {
  jQuery("targetelem").attr('readonly', true);
}
```

Here targetelem is input name. This is a easy way (there are more sophisticated alternatives) to get started.